# Can anyone help explain this schematic?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, swd

I'm having a hard time understanding if I will need both swd and st link or just one of them
[image]

My understanding is that the level shifter is there for the inputs given by the user which is the STLINK, and then you also have the SWD connectors and it should be similar as in the data it gives.

But I want someone to clear this for me and how they operate.

Comment: unclear what you are asking it appears this is an stlink debugger itself?  so one side is so that you can program the mcu on this board then the other header is so you can use this board to program other chips.  granted you need the right firmware on this board to make that all work...is this your goal?

Comment: what are you trying to build a breakout board for this stmf32f103 or a debugger or fill in the blank.  and note that this is the wrong site you want electrical engineering stackexchange not stackoverflow.

Comment: This is in no way a software programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [electronics.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to provide the schematic of the ST-Link-V2 side of a larger PCB. There are lots of different discovery/"nucleo"/eval boards from/with ST that include an **ST-Link** adapter and a target µC. The signals `T_SWCLK`/`T_SWDIO`/`T_SWO` and `STLK_TX`/`STLK_RX` go from the ST-Link controller to (the level shifter towards) the target controller, which sadly is not depicted in the question post. The former three signals mentioned above *are* the **SWV** connection (two signals **SWD** plus one for optional **SWO** tracing), while the latter two signals connect a full-duplex UART link to the target, which is provided by the ST-Link adapter and may be used to connect to the application target µC and help debug it or implement a bootloader.

Please note that the STM32F103CBT6 *is* the ST-Link controller. It is meant to be connected to a PC through the USB connector in the upper right corner.

As a next step you should inspect the other pages of that schematic (there must be some, because this page alone would be useless nonsense). Additionally, STM provides nice User Manuals for its Nucleo/Discovery boards, which include lots of detail information on different features - a good starting point to learn working with ST's development boards. Good luck.